# What is meant by saying that events happened before we started listening to them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

While reading for Javascript Promises, I have come across few blogs/articles where the Promise implementation is first compared with the Javascript Event model and then the callback pattern.

While comparing with the Event model, it is commonly mentioned that '**it's possible that the events happened before we started listening for them**' OR '**you need to ensure that all appropriate event handlers are added before the first time an event occurs**'

I'm trying to wrap my head around this and I'm not quite sure howz that possible from code standpoint. How can an event occur before we add the handlers ? Can anyone provide concrete examples to explain this ?

Comment: Sure, here is an example: `document.dispatchEvent(someClickEvent); document.addEventListener("click", myClickEventListener);` Code won't arbitrarily stop and wait for some unrelated code before it executes. The fact that you have one place where you set up event listeners won't make the other place that dispatches events stop and wait until the former is complete.

Answer (score 3):

They mean pretty much what they literally said: The event occurred before we started listening for it. For instance, suppose we show a button, but there's a delay of two seconds before we add an event handler listening for clicks on that button. If the user clicks within those two seconds, the event occurs before we were listening for it.

Example:

```js
function run() {
  // Show a button
  document.getElementById("btn").style.display = "inline";
  
  // Wait two seconds before we hook up a handler
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log("Got a click");
    }, false);
  }, 2000);
  
  // If the user clicks within those two seconds, the event happened
  // before we were listening for it.
}

// This is just stuff to make sure the user is ready before showing the button
var counter = 4;
tick();

function tick() {
  if (counter == 0) {
    document.getElementById("get-ready").style.display = "none";
    run();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = counter--;
    setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="get-ready">Get ready, a button will appear in <span id="countdown"></span>, click it as soon as it appears, then again a couple of seconds later:</p>
<input style="display: none" type="button" id="btn" value="Click me as soon as I appear, and again a couple of seconds later">
```

> What I was looking for was some generic cases where events are fired before we attach listeners.

Well, the above is quite generic: Consider the usual practice of putting your JavaScript in a `script` tag at the end of the document body, just before the closing `</body>` tag, or using the `async` or `defer` attributes on it. That means there is a brief period of time when any buttons on the page can be clicked, but we haven't hooked up handlers on them yet. If there's a temporary network glitch, for instance, and it takes two seconds instead of the usual ~65ms to load your JavaScript file, your users would click the button (trigger the event) before you hooked your handler (were listening for it).

Alternately, this used to be a good example, but <s>no longer happens on modern browsers as far as I can tell</s> *[Kaiido says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315372/what-is-meant-by-saying-that-events-happened-before-we-started-listening-to-them/39315451?noredirect=1#comment65965652_39315451) it still does on WebKit browsers, although I couldn't make it happen on iOS Safari*: Adding an `img` to a document and expecting to get the load event from code like this:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "path/to/the/image.png";
img.addEventListener("load", function() {
    // Handle the fact it loaded
}, false);
img.addEventListener("error", function() {
    // Handle the fact it failed
}, false);
someOtherElement.appendChild(img);
```

On the surface, it looks like there's no race condition there because of JavaScript's *run-to-completion* semantics and the fact that by default our JavaScript code runs on a single UI thread. But there *is* a race condition there, because while our code will follow a single thread, the *browser* is not single-threaded. So this can happen:

1. `img.src = "path/to/the/image.png";`.
2. The browser's resource management code goes looking for the image.
3. Resource management finds it in cache and doesn't need to re-verify, so associates the image data with the element and triggers the `load` event.
4. The event system goes to queue tasks for callbacks to any `load` event handlers that are present on the element, doesn't find any, and doesn't queue any tasks.
5. We attach our handlers and append the element.
6. Our code runs to completion.
7. We never get either a `load` or `error` event callback.

In contrast, if we hook *first* and then set `src`:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.addEventListener("load", function() {
    // Handle the fact it loaded
}, false);
img.addEventListener("error", function() {
    // Handle the fact it failed
}, false);
img.src = "path/to/the/image.png";          // <=== Moved
someOtherElement.appendChild(img);
```

Then the same scenario plays out like this:

1. We attach our handlers.
2. `img.src = "path/to/the/image.png";`.
3. The browser's resource management code goes looking for the image.
4. Resource management finds it in cache and doesn't need to re-verify, so associates the image data with the element and triggers the `load` event.
5. The event system goes to queue tasks for callbacks to any `load` event handlers that are present on the element. It finds one, so it queues a task to call it when the task queue is next empty.
6. We append the element.
7. Our code runs to completion.
8. The task loop picks up the next task from the queue, which happens to be our `load` callback.
9. The task loop calls our callback.

Now, it happens that this behavior was sufficiently irksome that modern browsers don't do it anymore *(although [Kaiido says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315372/what-is-meant-by-saying-that-events-happened-before-we-started-listening-to-them/39315451?noredirect=1#comment65965652_39315451) it still does on WebKit, I can't confirm that)*. Although I still code as though it does (the second example), because it *could*, it's a valid way for the browser to work.

Comment: Thanks this does make some sense but the scenario seems too specific(adding the listener with setTimeout). What I was looking for was some generic cases where events are fired before we attach listeners.

Comment: @bikash In general, you will likely have one part of your system that sets up the listeners. That will be completely decoupled from where the events are being sent. Sure, in this example, you have a very explicit delay before the listener is added but in a real system the same could happen for multitude of reasons - perhaps some part of the initialisations takes 2 seconds, and you add listeners afterwards, or you might wait for something to happen before adding them. At any rate, it's quite possible to have a delay without explicitly putting it in.

Comment: @bikash: I've added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot.My questions stems from an effort to better understand Promises and your reasoning makes perfect sense.Appreciate it !!!

Comment: @Kaiido: That's strange, I tried to make it happen on Chrome without luck. Just double-checked, and still got the event. (Hmmm, I suppose Chrome isn't strictly a webkit browser anymore since they went Blink, is it?) (Edit: Not happening for me in iOS Safari, either.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder,  strangely enough, I'm not able to force it either. But I could have swore I saw it happen less than 6 months ago on a chrome, and even more recently on Safari... I'll delete these comments.

Comment: @Kaiido: I'd say they're useful comments, might as well leave them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I'm still unable to reproduce it, but it seems some are still facing this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338648/adding-image-to-javascript-canvas-using-relative-file-path#comment-66008996

Comment: @Kaiido: Yeah, I'll keep coding defensively. :-)