# adding image to Javascript canvas using relative file path

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I feel like there is a very simple way to do this, yet I can't find it.  I have an image whose relative path to my `clientscript.js` file is `./images/orig classic pokemon frame.png`.  I want to draw it on the canvas, around the text that is drawn on the very last line of this code snippet:

```
function render(context) {
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.save();
    var imgFrame = new Image();
    imgFrame.src = './images/origclassicpokemonframe.png';
    imgFrame.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(imgFrame, 0, 0, 30,30);
    };
    context.font = "24px Early GameBoy";
    context.fillText("What? _____", 10, canvasHeight-44); //20 padding plus 24 line height
```

The text shows up on the canvas, but the frame never does.  Changing the dimensions or the x and y coordinates does not make a difference.  Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:  Changed the filepath to `images/origclassicpokemonframe.PNG` and now the image shows on canvas in firefox, but not chrome.
help????

Another edit:  I can see in the console on both chrome and firefox that the HTTP request is loading it just fine but somehow it just doesn't want to draw on the canvas.

Comment: Have you tried `'../images/orig classic pokemon frame.png;'`

Comment: try `imgFrame.onerror = (e)=>{console.log(e);}`

Comment: Have you tried using full path to resource?

Comment: is your 'clientscript.js' in the same directory as your `.html` file? relative paths are not relative to the location of the script . . .

Comment: This is going to sound whacky, but try `images/orig%20classic%20pokemon%20frame.PNG`

Comment: @Isaac, thanks, I just removed the spaces in the filename, but it's still not showing up on the canvas.

Comment: I also got the code to work in firefox. Perhaps Chrome is loading the image syncrhonously from cache: try changing the order of setting the onload handler and the image's source attribute so `onload` is set first

Comment: @Traktor53, thanks, that seemed to clear it up!

Comment: @Vendea, just out of curiosity, which version of chrome are you using?

Comment: @Kaiido  , the version of chrome was 53.0.2785.92  and firefox was 48.0 both running on Ubuntu (64-bit).

Answer (score -3):

`context` isn't a global variable. As such, using it in the 'onload' function is out of it's scope.

There was nothing wrong with your src if it would work in an `<img>` element.

Comment: it is in context, `function render(context) { ...`