# Why I get two different values in different browser?

Tags: javascript, dom

I wrote this code:

```js
var i = new Image() 
i.src = 'http://img1.vued.vanthink.cn/vudeaW1naW4wOjExOjA5MjM5OjQ1.jpeg';
i.onload = function() {
  //  i.width = 1024;
    $(i).css('width',1025/2); $('body').append(i);
    alert(i.width);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When I run that (for instance, in dev tools), I get 150 in Safari but 513 in Chrome:

[image]

[image]

Why?

Comment: (Not the problem, but note: You want to hook the event *before* setting `src`. [Details in an example in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39315451/157247)].)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks.I Got it.

Comment: Have you double-checked that the value of the `box-sizing` CSS property is not different between the two browsers?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that by using jQuery to hook up the onload event, does it as you expect

```html
var i = new Image() 
$(i).css('width',1024/2);
$('body').append(i)
$(i).load(function()
{  
     alert($(i).width());     
});
i.src="55141873_46dbf53454_o.jpg";
```

Comment: At least that worked for me in that Chrome and safari both output 512

Comment: the load function doesn't do what you think (it loads data from an ajax call and appends it to the element it's been called on), the correct way to bind the load event in jquery is .one("load", function() {